How to verify the granularity of memory access interleaving across different channels?
According to AMD's material, access to contiguous physical addresses will be interleaved across all memory channels (if set to NPS1). When a machine has 8 memory channels and the size of memory interleaving is set to 256 bytes, if the program intentionally accesses the first 256 bytes in every 2K space, it is expected that all memory access bandwidth will be concentrated on a specific channel.
However, I found through code testing that the memory access bandwidth is still evenly distributed across all memory channels.
Total Mem Bw (GB/s),26.34,0.23
Total Mem RdBw (GB/s),26.23,0.13
Total Mem WrBw (GB/s),0.11,0.10
Mem Ch-A RdBw (GB/s),3.27,0.02
Mem Ch-A WrBw (GB/s),0.01,0.01
Mem Ch-B RdBw (GB/s),3.27,0.02
Mem Ch-B WrBw (GB/s),0.01,0.01
Mem Ch-C RdBw (GB/s),3.29,0.02
Mem Ch-C WrBw (GB/s),0.01,0.01
Mem Ch-D RdBw (GB/s),3.29,0.02
Mem Ch-D WrBw (GB/s),0.02,0.01
Mem Ch-E RdBw (GB/s),3.27,0.02
Mem Ch-E WrBw (GB/s),0.01,0.01
Mem Ch-F RdBw (GB/s),3.27,0.02
Mem Ch-F WrBw (GB/s),0.01,0.01
Mem Ch-G RdBw (GB/s),3.28,0.02
Mem Ch-G WrBw (GB/s),0.02,0.01
Mem Ch-H RdBw (GB/s),3.28,0.02
Mem Ch-H WrBw (GB/s),0.01,0.01

Why is this?
Below is the core logic of my code.
#define INTERLEAVE_LEN 256
#define CHANNEL_NUM 8
#define STEP_LEN (128)

#define ADDR_BOUNDRY_INST (1UL << 7)    // instruction aligned to 128B
const uint64_t addr_mask_inst = ~(ADDR_BOUNDRY_INST-1);

while(!should_stop){

    for(uint64_t j = 0; j < INTERLEAVE_LEN/STEP_LEN; ++j){
        memread_128B_32Bstep((char*)(c_test_area+pos1));
        pos1 = (((pos1 + STEP_LEN) % cur_memsize) & cur_mask);
    }

    pos1 = (((pos1 + INTERLEAVE_LEN*(CHANNEL_NUM-1)) % cur_memsize) & cur_mask);
}

static inline void memread_128B_32Bstep(char* memarea)
{
    asm volatile(
        "mov    %[memarea], %%rax \n"   // rcx = reset loop iterator
        "vmovdqa 0*32(%%rax), %%ymm0 \n"
        "vmovdqa 1*32(%%rax), %%ymm0 \n"
        "vmovdqa 2*32(%%rax), %%ymm0 \n"
        "vmovdqa 3*32(%%rax), %%ymm0 \n"
        : 
        : [memarea] "r" (memarea)
        : "rax", "xmm0", "memory");
}

The virtual addresses are aligned to 4K, and the allocated pages are all 2M large pages.
#define ADDR_BOUNDRY (1UL << 12)    
const uint64_t addr_boundry = ADDR_BOUNDRY;
const uint64_t addr_mask = ~(ADDR_BOUNDRY-1);
char* tmp = (char*)malloc(mem_size + addr_boundry);

c_test_area = (char*)(((uint64_t)tmp + addr_boundry) & addr_mask);

I'm using AMD EPYC 7713 for test

more result update:
I disabled all hardware prefetcher in the BIOS and verified it using the hwpfdc metric in amduprof, but the results did not change.
I adjusted the granularity at each step, touching one cache line every 4K or 16K, but the results did not change.
I changed YMM to regular scalar instructions, and the results did not change.

Did you disable HW prefetch?  4 contiguous fetches will probably trigger it, pulling in some of the next 256 bytes.  Also, on a 9600X (Zen 5) desktop I just built, the interleave granularity is a BIOS firmware config option.  (ASRock B650M Pro RS).  EPYC memory controllers might also have that option.

Why inline asm and YMM?  This is cacheable memory, right?  So you just need a volatile char* deref in each 64-byte cache line.  If this is on Linux, you left it running long enough for kcompactd to finish any copying of pages to allow for coalescing into 2M largepages?  (If THP defrag is enabled at all).  Also, why malloc?  posix_memalign and aligned_alloc make it easy to get 4K or 2M or even 1G alignment for allocations.

@PeterCordes I found the relevant configuration in the BIOS and manually set it to 256B. The reason for using YMM is that this part of the code was previously used to test memory bandwidth limits under different conditions, and I reused it directly. I did not use THP. Instead, I used pre-allocated huge pages with libhugetlbfs.so. I used malloc for convenience, and after adding manual alignment, it should be equivalent.

@PeterCordes I disabled all hardware prefetching features in the BIOS, but the result did not change.

Ok, that is surprising.  Update your question with all those details.  Have you tried experimenting with larger strides, like touching one cache line every 4K or 16K, to see if that always aliases the same memory channel?  Just one cache line, not two like you're doing now.

@PeterCordes I just tried it, and the results did not change. I have added the relevant information in the question.

How do you measure total and per-channel memory bandwidth?  I assume you're getting enough TLB hits that page-walks aren't creating tons of traffic on other channels?

@PeterCordes I used the uprof tool provided by AMD to collect bandwidth information. I used 2M huge pages, with an overall footprint of 8GB, and the access pattern is mostly sequential, so there are not many TLB misses. The MPTI for L2-DTLB obtained from monitoring is 0.12
